# How to reorganize a large Excel File

Tags: microsoft-excel

A friend of mine has "inherited" an Excel worksheet that was used as an address file.

Unfortunately the person who created it had the horrible idea of making it like this:

```
Name   |Lorem               |Surname  |Ipsum               |ZipCode | 10139
Street |Lorem Street        |City     |Ipumvillw           |Tel     | 01020302
       |                    |         |                    |        |
Name   |Lorem               |Surname  |Ipsum               |ZipCode | 10139
Street |Lorem Street        |City     |Ipumvillw           |Tel     | 01020302
       |                    |         |                    |        |
Name   |Lorem               |Surname  |Ipsum               |ZipCode | 10139
Street |Lorem Street        |City     |Ipumvillw           |Tel     | 01020302
       |                    |         |                    |        |
Name   |Lorem               |Surname  |Ipsum               |ZipCode | 10139
Street |Lorem Street        |City     |Ipumvillw           |Tel     | 01020302
```

And of course my friend would like to reformat this as:

```
|Name         | Surname      |Tel       |City         |Street    |ZipCode |
|Lorem        |Ipsum         |01010101  |Ipsumville   |Lorem St. |10139   |
|    ...      | ...          | ...      | ...         | ...      |  ...   |
|Lorem        |Ipsum         |01010101  |Ipsumville   |Lorem St. |10139   |
|Lorem        |Ipsum         |01010101  |Ipsumville   |Lorem St. |10139   |
```

I could probably save it as csv, cobble together a Perl script to parse the csv and reorganize it in a more sensible way, but I am busy atm so if someone has some non-programming solution I'd see if he can manage it by himself.

---

**Bad news**
The spreasheet is not regular. I.e. a whole address may span more than 2 rows, and this is more or less random. Apparently this is a sort of report from some small-potatoes accounting program, they print to file and then slurp it in Excel.
I will not see if [parse-o-matic](http://www.dataparse.com) can help.

(I am looking at Parse-O-Matic because I used it for a similar problem years ago, a free basic version exists, and I hope that it may be useuful for my friend as a general purpose tool in the future).

Comment: It looks to me like you already have your best solution, to export it as a CSV, then concatenate every pair of lines.  `sed` would be my choice:  `sed 'N; s/\n/, /;p'`.

Comment: I haven't seen an actual copy of the file (yet), just a screenshot so not 100% sure that there aren't creative surprises below the first few lines. Assuming it's regular, yes, that's probably the best way - I just hoped I could find something that didn't require me to work on it  (yeah, I am lazy...)

Comment: The approach I explained in my answer still works even for irregular data sets like yours. The exact instructions would depend on the max number of lines a record in this sheet could have.

Comment: @Alex P. - I sent the link to this question to my friend, so if he can make your answer work I will be glad to accept it!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. Let's say you have your data starting from `A1` cell:

> | A1 | B1 | C1 | ...
>
> | A2 | B2 | C2 | ...

In the 1st empty cell of the top row type in formula `=A2` and drag/fill the cell to the right for the same number of columns so you would get your sheet looking like this:

> | A1 | B1 | C1 | ... | =A2 | =B2 | =C2 | ...
>
> | A2 | B2 | C2 | ...

1. select all the cells with formulae in that top row and drag/fill it down for the rest of the lines
2. select the whole sheet, then copy and paste special (only values) to another sheet
3. in that new sheet filter out everything but lines with "Name" in the 1st column
4. make headers for the columns with actual data
5. delete columns with the old headers

Comment: Took me a second to understand the approach - but pretty smart! +1

Answer (score 0):

I don’t guarantee that this is much less effort than the other ideas that have been suggested, but here’s my solution; I translated

[image]

to

[image]

(on `Sheet2`). The formulae are:

- `A2`: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1, ROW()*3-6, 0, 1, 1)`
- `B2`: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$1, ROW()*3-6, 0, 1, 1)`
- `C2`: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$F$2, ROW()*3-6, 0, 1, 1)`
- `D2`: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$2, ROW()*3-6, 0, 1, 1)`
- `E2`: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2, ROW()*3-6, 0, 1, 1)`
- `F2`: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$F$2, ROW()*3-6, 0, 1, 1)`

and of course you drag/fill down.  The first parameter in each `OFFSET` call is the location of the first occurrence of the desired field in the first sheet; e.g., you want `Tel` in Column `C`, and the first `Tel` in `Sheet1` is in cell `F2`.  You multiply the current row number by 3 because each “record” on `Sheet2` is just one row, but the records on `Sheet1` are three rows each.  The –6 is just a fudge factor to get it to come out right, assuming that you have headings on `Sheet2` and there aren’t any on `Sheet1` –– the first record is on row 2, and 2*3 is 6, but, to access `Sheet1!B1` by an offset from `Sheet1!B1`, you need an offset of 0 (hence, subtract 6).

You can keep Sheet2 linked to Sheet1 in perpetuity, or you can copy and paste values, and discard it.

Comment: Pfft, in my case you need to type in just a single very short formula (=A2) then drag/fill to the right... then drag/fill down. that's it. no need to calculate offsets. and if there are extra and/or missing empty rows in between you would not even notice...

Comment: @Alex, while you've presented a good general approach (which I've used many times when I could count on perfect regularity of the data), note that your specific recommendation--to drag the formula `=A2` across to the right and down--does not fit the example data.  Assuming the data begin in A1, what would be needed in the first row to produce the desired layout is the formulas "=B1", "=D1", "=F2", "=D2", "=B2", and "=F1". If extra rows were possible, conditional logic would need to be added to the formulas to make sure they were picking up the right data references.

Comment: @chuff, you clearly did not understand the approach. It's much faster to rearrange column order in the end than make custom formulas for every column.

Comment: @Alex: Read the words.  Chuff said that you “presented a good general approach,” but you left out a lot of details, and you miffed some of the ones that you did provide.  It’s hard to compare the complexity of two answers when one is presented in accurate detail, and the other is presented as a concept with a hand waved at the details.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a possible solution:

1. Create a new empty sheet.
2. In the original sheet, create an automatic filter and and filter by "Name" on the first column. This will "select" all odd rows. Select and copy in the new sheet.
3. Create another filter, using a different cell content (Street). This will select all even rows. Copy these in the new sheet, placing the rows to the immediate right of the first selection.
4. Same approach could work if your data is distributed on 3 or more rows (my example has only two, but this may work for 3 or more rows patterns).
5. Create a row at the top, add field name
6. Remove the columns where the field labels were.